# How to send output of Powershell script to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, azure

I have been given the following script to connect to an Azure subscription, get all the certificates and output some of the certificate properties.
The script works fine, 
**What I am trying to do is send the output into a CSV file** so I can sort by certificate expiry-date (for example) and manipulate the output into spreadsheet reports (for instance).

### Powershell Script

```
Set-AzureSubscription 'MySubscription'
Select-AzureSubscription 'MySubscription'

$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$azcerts = Get-AzureService | Get-AzureCertificate
foreach ($azcert in $azcerts) {      
    $bytes = $enc.GetBytes($azcert.data) 
    $cert = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate -ArgumentList @(,$bytes)    
    $subjectstring = $cert.Subject
    $expirydate = $cert.GetExpirationDateString()
    $servicename = $azcert.ServiceName
    $thumprint = $azcert.Thumbprint
    $cnstring = $subjectstring -replace "(CN=)(.*?),.*",'$2'    
    Write-Output "$servicename, $cnstring, $expirydate, $thumprint"    }
```

#### What I have tried...

When I try to replace the last line in the for-each loop with this I get a useless CSV file with only one column "#TYPE System.String"

```
"$servicename, $cnstring, $expirydate, $thumprint" | Export-Csv "outputfile.csv" -append -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Might want to look at the Format-Custom, Format-List, Format-Table and Format-Wide Cmdlets.  I'm sure using one of those you'll get your format in the layout you want to import into Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made you're own CSV lines in the loop so you can just write to disk:

```
"$servicename, $cnstring, $expirydate, $thumprint" | Out-File -FilePath output.csv -Append -Encoding ASCII
```

before the loop write your headers:

```
"servicename, cnstring, expirydate, thumprint" | Out-File -FilePath output.csv -Encoding ASCII
```

For `Export-Csv` or `ConvertTo-Csv` to work you'd need to pipe a collection of objects with these fields as properties. You could make such a collection using `New-Object`:

```
New-Object -TypeName PsObject -Property @{servicename=$servicename;cnstring=$cnstring <ETC...>}
```